# Problem with excel (vba) Division by zero (Error 11) debugging

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new in VBA and I have an Excel sheet in which some macros are running. In one of the tabs, users can input data and by pressing the command button on the sheet they can get the answer. Now I want to enter data via a userform. I've successfully created an userform and it can perfectly read/write data from the Excel sheet. The problem I am facing now is that as soon as I enter the data in the userform, the command button (which is connected to a macro) gives me "Division by zero" error, and it kinda ruins the Excel file and I need to replace it with the backup file I have! I can't understand why entering data via the userform causes this problem.

When I enter data on the Excel sheet (not via userform) everything is fine!!! This is the part I'm getting the error:

```vb
Function ATn2(x As Variant, Y As Variant) As Double
    If x = 0 Then
        If Y = 0 Then
            ATn2 = 1 / 0
        ElseIf Y > 0 Then
            ATn2 = Pi / 2
        Else
            ATn2 = -Pi / 2
        End If
    ElseIf x > 0 Then
        If Y = 0 Then
            ATn2 = 0
        Else
            ATn2 = Atn(Y / x)
        End If
    Else
        If Y = 0 Then
            ATn2 = Pi
        Else
            ATn2 = (Pi - Atn(Abs(Y) / Abs(x))) * Sgn(Y)
        End If
    End If 
End Function
```

And of course I can see that the error is coming from `ATn2 = 1 / 0` :)

Comment: `1/0` cannot work in any circumstance. The code worked only when y <> 0.  Anyhow, try changing `ATn2(x As Variant, Y As Variant)` with `ATn2(x As Double, Y As Double)`. Not for solving the division by zero error...

Comment: `And of course I can see that the error is coming from ATn2 = 1 / 0` - so you are aware that it happens because you are calling `ATn2(0, 0)`. So don't do that.

Comment: FaneDuru and GSerg, thank you for your comments. Yes, I know that is the problem, but I cannot completely follow the code since I haven't written it, and also I cannot understand why It doesn't happen when I enter the data in the excel sheet! only putting data by userform causing this problem

Answer (score -1):

by allowing the option of ATn2 = 1 / 0 if both x and Y are 0 you are creating the divide by zero error. In the other instances of Y = 0 you have specified either Pi or 0 as the return value.

Perhaps you should change the 1 / 0 to a different value.

```
Function ATn2(x As Variant, Y As Variant) As Double
If x = 0 Then
    If Y = 0 Then
        ' // BOTH ARGUMENTS ARE ZERO
        MsgBox ("Values are both zero and cannot be calculated")
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Y > 0 Then
        ATn2 = Pi / 2
    Else
        ATn2 = -Pi / 2
    End If
ElseIf x > 0 Then
    If Y = 0 Then
        ATn2 = 0
    Else
        ATn2 = Atn(Y / x)
    End If
Else
    If Y = 0 Then
        ATn2 = Pi
    Else
        ATn2 = (Pi - Atn(Abs(Y) / Abs(x))) * Sgn(Y)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I believe it is intentional to raise the division by zero error when both arguments are actually zero.

Comment: It is extremely wrong to call a message box from a function that is supposed to return a value.

Comment: Thank you for your response Pete, but since I need that value, putting a msg won't help me :)

Comment: The value of anything divided by zero will error - You say putting the values direct into a sheet does not result in an error. If you manually enter x = 0 and Y = 0 on the sheet, what value to you get?

Comment: Well I don't enter X and Y as inout!!! It is really lengthy micro which is just reading a few inputs (not all related to X and Y) and then calculate sth! but the X and Y are defined in the micro itself, which I cannot exactly follow it. It is reading from another function I think

Answer (score -2):

This may help

```
Public Function ATan2(ByVal ipY As Double, ByVal ipX As Double) As Double
    
    Dim myTheta As Double

    If (Abs(ipX) < 0.0000001) Then
    
        If (Abs(ipY) < 0.0000001) Then
        
            myTheta = 0#
            
        ElseIf (ipY > 0#) Then
        
            myTheta = 1.5707963267949

        Else
        
            myTheta = -1.5707963267949
            
        End If
        
    Else
    
        myTheta = Atn(ipY / ipX)
  
        If (ipX < 0) Then
        
            If (ipY >= 0#) Then
            
                myTheta = 3.14159265358979 + myTheta
                
            Else
            
                myTheta = myTheta - 3.14159265358979
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    ATan2 = myTheta
    
End Function
```